How do i know when it's safe to shut-down my out-of-process COM automation server?
Short Version
As soon as my COM automation server starts up, and registers its class objects, i check if there are any references that need to keep me alive. There aren't. So i shutdown - before anything gets a chance to happen.
What is the pattern to stick around long enough without any references to any of my objects, but then not stick around after there are no longer any references to any of my objects?
Long Version
If you are an out-of-process COM automation server, you have a number of goals. Assume we are implementing a Single-Threaded Apartment (STA) server; meaning we will be pumping a message loop.
My sample implemenatation i think follows the standard route from our WinMain:

Note: I will use a C#-like syntax, but i am not referring to managed code. I'm showing you code that looks like C# so you don't have to see my native Delphi. Additionally I am asking a language-agnostic question; just like COM is desgined to be language-agnostic - that's its entire reason for living - binary interoperability


Use CoRegisterClassObject to register my "class object"; which is an object that implements IClassFactory:
// Create an instance of our class factory
IClassFactory classFactory = new ApeFactory();

// Initialize the COM infrastructure
CoInitialize(null);

// Register our class factory, and keep the cookie to unregister it later
DWORD dwCookie;
HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(classFactory, out dwCookie);

This class object will then be called upon to create our Ape object.
Our IClassFactory does not implement reference counting with its AddRef/Release methods. This is because for the duration that the COM Service Manager (CSM) is holding onto a reference to our ApeFactory our application can't shutdown (because someone's using one of our objects). But the CSM won't release the references to our class objects until we call CoRevokeClassObject. This catch-22 is why IExternalConnection was created:
IExternalConnection = interface
{
   // Increments the count of an object's strong external connections.
   DWORD AddConnection(DWORD extconn, DWORD reserved);

   // Decrements the count of an object's strong external connections.
   DWORD ReleaseConnection(DWORD extconn, DWORD reserved,BOOL fLastReleaseCloses);
}

This interface lets us:

differentiate between "external" people referencing our objects
as opposed to just COM holding onto our objects

We only really need to keep our automation server alive if there is some external client somewhere who got ahold of our IClassFactory. If it's just COM holding onto our object, then we can shutdown fine.
So COM will tell us when some "external" user is referencing our class factory. This means we can then maintain a global lock count:
Int64 g_ModuleReferenceCount;     

Then perform an atomic increment during AddConnection, and an atomic decrement during ReleaseConnection.

Start our message loop
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
   TranslateMessage(ref msg);
   DispatchMessage(ref msg);

   // check if our external reference counts have gone to zero; meaning we can shutdown
   if (g_ExternalReferenceCount <= 0)
      PostQuitMesage(msg.wParam);
}


Unregister our class objects during our orderly shutdown
// Unregister our ApeFactory IClassFactory
CoRevokeClassObject(dwCookie);


And our automation server gracefully shuts down.


Except for the race condition
If you look at the code together you can see the race condition:
void WinMain()
{
   // Register our class factory, and keep the cookie to unregister it later
   DWORD dwCookie;
   HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(classFactory, out dwCookie);

   // Setup our count of external references
   Int64 g_ModuleReferenceCount = 0; 

   MSG msg;
   while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
   {
      TranslateMessage(ref msg);
      DispatchMessage(ref msg);

      // check if our external reference counts have gone to zero; meaning we can shutdown
      if (g_ExternalReferenceCount <= 0)
         PostQuitMesage(msg.wParam);
   }

   // Unregister our ApeFactory IClassFactory
   CoRevokeClassObject(dwCookie);
}

Our module reference count starts at zero, and so before COM has a chance to even create our ApeFactory class object, we're unregistering the class factory and shutting down.
What is the pattern to employ here to stick around at least long enough to server some COM classes and COM objects?
"What about LockServer?"
I'm not muddying the waters with IClassFactory.LockServer. As Don Box noted:

Although the technique of using IExternalConnection on class objects has worked since the early days of COM, few implementors actually used this technique. Instead, most servers would typically ignore outstanding external references to class objects and prematurely terminate their server processes. This situation was encouraged by the presence of the method LockServer on the IClassFactory interface, which lulled developers into thinking that clients could actually ensure that a server would remain running. While most server implementors would properly lock their module in their LockServer methods, there was no reliable way for a client to call this method.

(emphasis mine)
So many implementations mistakenly relied upon LockServer to workaround their buggy code. But there's very little (i.e. no) documentation on the intended way to keep an STA COM automation server alive.
Don then goes on to explain the workaround the COM team applied to try to salvage these buggy apps:

Acknowledging that many server implementations were not using IExternalConnection to manage server lifetime properly, the Windows NT 4.0 release of COM introduced the following enhancement to compensate for these naive implementations:
When marshaling a reference to a class object in response to a CoGetClassObject call, the SCM will call the class object's IClassFactory::LockServer method. Since the vast majority of servers implement IClassFactory on their class objects, this enhancement to the COM runtimes repairs most defects. However, if a class object does not export the IClassFactory interface or if the server must also execute on pre-Window NT 4.0 releases of COM, the IExternalConnection technique must be used.

I want to pretend that LockServer is not an option because:

a) i want to underststand the correct way to do it
b) i don't understand how LockServer doesn't have the same race condition

I want to finally have added to Stackoverflow some documentation on the correct way to run a COM automation server.
Hacky workaround, or actual design pattern?
The issue is:

How do i stay around long enough for COM to start bootstrapping into my process?

Once COM starts calling:

IClassFactory.CreateInstance, or
IClassFactory.LockServer

we can incrementing global reference counts, and everything will be good as my regular reference counting through IExternalConnection will keep the server alive.
But the issue is how to remain around long enough for that to happen.
So perhaps a timer.
COM already mechanisms in place that involve pinging every 2 minutes, and if a server hasn't responded to 3 consective pings (6 minutes), COM considers the server dead. So perhaps a 6 minute timer. Or even a 30 second timer.
Something long enough that COM has a chance to start taking STRONG references to objects.
And that idea sounds so simple that it cannot be valid.
And I'm not the first person to implement an out-of-process, Single-threaded Apartment (STA), COM automation server; but finding examples in GitHub, Stackoverflow, Microsoft documentation, Sample code, in books, or even in the Windows NT 4, Windows 2000, or Windows XP source code finds no canonical patterns.

I don't think there's any magic bullet. FWIW, COM+ application configuration allows two settings: 1) never shutdown (like Office apps I believe) or 2) wait for x minutes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd145580(v=ws.11). PS: It's often better to write a classic in-process .dll and have COM+ host it as an out-of-process Server, IMHO this is an underrated solution to out-of-process COM server development, has lots of configurable features, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coreleaseserverprocess

@HansPassant "The simplest way for a local server application to make use of these functions is to call CoAddRefServerProcess in the constructor for each of its instance objects"  Same problem: that just farms out the reference count from my g_ModuleReferenceCount to a variable maintained by COM. I end up with the same problem: either i never shut down because i have a reference, or i shut down right away because there is no reference yet.

@IanBoyd add to g_ModuleReferenceCount special condition bit and left another 31 bits for ReferenceCount - too hard idea ? anyway i use it both time in solutions. different only - are you by self from some point decide stop server - first solution. or you stop server when count of clients became zero first time after non zero (second solution)

we can resolve problem with some kind of Run-Down Protection.
because no user mode support for this, need custom implementation. it can be next
// general base class
class RundownProtection
{
    LONG _Value;

public:

    enum {
        v_complete = 0, v_init = 1 << 31
    };

    BOOL IsRundownCompleted()
    {
        return v_complete == _Value;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL IsRundownBegin()
    {
        return 0 <= _Value;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL Acquire()
    {
        LONG Value, NewValue;

        if (0 > (Value = _Value))
        {
            do 
            {
                NewValue = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(&_Value, Value + 1, Value);

                if (NewValue == Value) return TRUE;

            } while (0 > (Value = NewValue));
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL Release()
    {
        return InterlockedDecrement(&_Value) == v_complete;
    }

    // if (Acquire()) { Rundown_l(); Release(); }
    void Rundown_l()
    {
        InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&_Value, 31);
    }

    RundownProtection(LONG Value = v_complete) : _Value(Value)
    {
    }

    BOOL Init()
    {
        return InterlockedCompareExchange(&_Value, v_init, v_complete) == v_complete;
    }
};

// implementation for concrete case

class ServerProtection : public RundownProtection
{
    ULONG _M_dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

public:

    ServerProtection() : RundownProtection(v_init)
    {
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (RundownProtection::Release())
        {
            PostThreadMessageW(_M_dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void Rundown()
    {
        if (Acquire())
        {
            Rundown_l(); 
            Release();
        }
    }
} _G_rp;

we can use it in next way inside Ape class
class CApe : public IApe
{
    // ...

    ~CApe()
    {
        _G_rp.Release();
    }

public:
    static HRESULT CreateInstance(_In_  REFIID riid, _COM_Outptr_  void **ppvObject)
    {
        if (_G_rp.Acquire())
        {
            if (CApe* pObj = new CApe)
            {
                HRESULT hr = pObj->QueryInterface(riid, ppvObject);

                pObj->Release();

                return hr;
            }

            _G_rp.Release();

            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }

        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_DELETE_PENDING);
    }
};

so we create new CApe only if _G_rp.Acquire() return true and call _G_rp.Release(); in destructor. if we fail create Ape after _G_rp.Acquire() we direct in place call _G_rp.Release();
this give us 2 things - until exist instance of Ape object - WM_QUIT (from ServerProtection::Release ) will be not called, and after _G_rp.Rundown() call - any call to _G_rp.Acquire() return FALSE
implementation of ApeFactory is simply
class __declspec(uuid("...")) ApeFactory : public IClassFactory
{
    // ...

    virtual /* [local] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CreateInstance( 
        /* [annotation][unique][in] */ 
        _In_opt_  IUnknown *pUnkOuter,
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        _In_  REFIID riid,
        /* [annotation][iid_is][out] */ 
        _COM_Outptr_  void **ppvObject)
    {
        *ppvObject = 0;

        return pUnkOuter ? CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION : CApe::CreateInstance(riid, ppvObject);
    }
};

and main server loop:
if (0 <= CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED|COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE))
{
    if (ApeFactory* pfc = new ApeFactory)
    {
        ULONG dwRegister;
        if (0 <= CoRegisterClassObject(__uuidof(ApeFactory), static_cast<IClassFactory*>(pfc), 
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &dwRegister))
        {
            MSG msg;
            while (0 < GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                switch (msg.wParam)
                {
                case WM_NULL:// some internal signal/message 
                    _G_rp.Rundown();
                    break;
                }
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            }

            CoRevokeClassObject(dwRegister);
        }

        pfc->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}

so hen we want stop server, we basen on some event call _G_rp.Rundown(); - note we can safe call _G_rp.Rundown(); multiple time and in concurrent - result will be ok. the _G_rp.Rundown(); can direct initiate server shutdown, if no Ape objects at current time, or otherwise - prevent create new Ape and when it count became 0 - start shutdown.
really all idea and implementation of rundown protection - is combination of reference/objects count and 1 bit flag in single DWORD (32 bit value- 31 bit for object/ref count and 1 bit for rundown tag). and interlocked manipulate with this


my .exe just has to remain running, pumping messages, until there are
no outstanding references to any of my COM objects.

how i can understand this - we want shutdown server after count of clients first time reach to zero. from my view - strange logic, but implementation almost the same. main idea not changed - we need hold in sigle int (32 bits) variable 2 thing - count of clients (31 bit) and some logical bit. and do atomic(interlocked) modification of this variable.
class ServerProtection
{
    LONG _Value = MINLONG;// 0x80000000 
    ULONG _M_dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

public:

    _NODISCARD BOOL Acquire()
    {
        LONG Value, NewValue;

        if (0 > (Value = _Value))
        {
            do 
            {
                NewValue = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(&_Value, Value + 1, Value);

                if (NewValue == Value) return TRUE;

            } while (0 > (Value = NewValue));
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    void Release()
    {
        LONG Value = _Value, NewValue;

        for(;;Value = NewValue) 
        {
            NewValue = Value - 1;

            if (NewValue == MINLONG)
            {
                NewValue = 0;
            }

            NewValue = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(&_Value, NewValue, Value);

            if (NewValue == Value) 
            {
                if (MINLONG + 1 == Value)
                {
                    PostThreadMessageW(_M_dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
                }
                return ;
            }
        }
    }

} _G_rp;

the code of CApe not changed - we need call _G_rp.Acquire() before new CApe and call _G_rp.Release(); from destructor. changed only main loop, became more simpy - because now not exist Rundown method
if (0 <= CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED|COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE))
{
    if (ApeFactory* pfc = new ApeFactory)
    {
        ULONG dwRegister;
        if (0 <= CoRegisterClassObject(__uuidof(ApeFactory), static_cast<IClassFactory*>(pfc), 
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &dwRegister))
        {
            MSG msg;
            while (0 < GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            }

            CoRevokeClassObject(dwRegister);
        }

        pfc->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}


and if somebody dont understand idea combine in single variable counter and separate flag, for atomic change both - this yet not mean that idea or implementation wrong (if no POC which prove this). may be somebody simply dont understand

That doesn't seem to answer the question.

@IInspectable question is how safe shutdown server, and i give answer exactly on this. If you have better/another solution, of found error in my - can post self answer or arguing where error

The question is asking how to find the point in time when it's safe to initiate COM server shutdown. This proposed answer fails to address that question.

@IInspectable no. I say - 32 bit value is used for this , in class, RundownProtection and when it becomes 0 - safe initiate server shutdown

Who posts WM_NULL, and when?

@IanBoyd - posts WM_NULL - your code. but here WM_NULL is demo only. in it place can be any. your code decide somehow stop server. and call _G_rp.Rundown(); at this point

So lets say i use PostQuitMessage rather than WM_NULL. When do i know it's safe to call PostQuitMessage? I can then call rundown, and since i don't have any external references (yet) my COM server will shutdown before COM has a chance to use the ClassFactory to create any Ape objects.

@IanBoyd So lets say i use PostQuitMessage rather than WM_NULL - of course no. use  PostQuitMessage you can only after rundown end, inside ServerProtection::Release. i use here PostThreadMessageW(_M_dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0) because this will be work from any thread, while PostQuitMessage can be used only if final ServerProtection::Release will be called from UI thread. you want stop own server at some point or not ? and when you want do this - call _G_rp.Rundown();. after this ServerProtection::Release will be called (just of after last Ape destroyed).

@IanBoyd you break message loop (via WM_QUIT or PostQuitMessage if you sure that all happens in the same thread, but WM_QUIT more general solution) after rundown copleted (look ServerProtection::Release ) and rundown completed - after you by self call _G_rp.Rundown(); and no more Ape objects. only when RundownProtection::_Value became 0 - the WM_QUIT will be post. however 0 in _Value mean that no more Ape object and can not be created new after this, because Acquire return false

@IanBoyd and you must want by self stop server process at some point. by some signal - say from UI (user action) or from service manager (if you implement own server as service) or by some else signal. if you not want stop server by self - your question lost sense - simply never break message loop and all

An out-of-process COM server does not have to be an NT Service, nor does it have to ever show any UI. COM calls CreateProcess to launch my PlanetOfTheApes.exe, and my .exe just has to remain running, pumping messages, until there are no outstanding references to any of my COM objects.

@IanBoyd - so client create object (Ape), client release object, now 0 objects, and you want terminate. Yes ?

But i don't create the Ape object, someone else creates the Ape object. I create the factory that creates the Ape objects.

@IanBoyd and so what ? You can say - based on what criteria you want shutdown? Because look like you at all don't understand what you want and what you ask.
